# stll no users table after migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sinatra

I'm working along with the book Service Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails. In the first chapter, it creates a service with a Sinatra application using active record. I created the active record migration (001_create_users.rb, see below), and ran the rake file to migrate it (using the command `rake db:migrate`), and it gave me output which seemed to indicate the users table was created (see the bottom of this post for the output after running rake db:migrate). However, when I ran the specs (`rspec spec/service_spec.rb`, see below), it gave me an error saying that it couldn't find the users table.

```
table_structure': Could not find table 'users' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong? The source code for the first chapter of the book can also be found here https://github.com/pauldix/service-oriented-design-with-ruby/tree/master/chapter_01

**spec/service_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

describe "service" do
  before(:each) do
    User.delete_all
  end

  describe "GET on /api/v1/users/:id" do
    before(:each) do
      User.create(
        :name => "paul",
        :email => "paul@pauldix.net",
        :password => "strongpass",
        :bio => "rubyist")
    end

    it "should return a user by name" do
      get '/api/v1/users/paul'
      last_response.should be_ok
      attributes = JSON.parse(last_response.body)["user"]
      attributes["name"].should == "paul"
    end
```

**/db/migrate/001_create_users.rb**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :bio

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Rakefile

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'
require 'logger'

desc "Load the environment"
task :environment do
  env = ENV["SINATRA_ENV"] || "development"
  databases = YAML.load_file("config/database.yml")
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(databases[env])
end

namespace :db do
  desc "Migrate the database"
  task(:migrate => :environment) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = true
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate")
  end
end
```

**After running rake db:migrate**

```
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.490937 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.493906 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL) 
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.497176 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (2.6ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.544128 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (44.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
I, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.544615 #3824]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateUsers (1)
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.545263 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.570509 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varchar(255), "password" varchar(255), "bio" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) 
   -> 0.0018s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.0019s) ===========================================

D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.571113 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('1')
D, [2013-03-08T20:11:55.576187 #3824] DEBUG -- :    (4.8ms)  commit transaction
michael$ rspec spec/service_spec.rb
D, [2013-03-08T20:12:57.812685 #3854] DEBUG -- : env: test
D, [2013-03-08T20:12:57.910829 #3854] DEBUG -- : db/test.sqlite3 database connection established...
```

Comment: usually the test database is different from your development database. make sure you create your test database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `migrate` task calls `environment` as prerequisite which sets the environment to "development" by default, unless there's an ENV variable saying something else.

What happens is that your dev DB gets migrated, but not your test DB.

Like the instructions for your book say, a little after, call

```
rake db:migrate SINATRA_ENV=test
```

And it'll be your *test* DB being migrated.

Comment: my edition of the book doesn't say that (at least not that I can see), but thanks

Comment: https://github.com/pauldix/service-oriented-design-with-ruby/blob/master/chapter_01/README#L35

Comment: other alternative is `RACK_ENV=test rake db:migrate`